# Activity Feed in MySQL only

Tags: mysql, android-activity, feed

I want to create a activity_feed system that use mysql only. The activity will be displayed to the followers of users that make the activity. The activity itself will be written (after some interrogation to other DB, for example "posts") in another cache table.

```
**ACTIVITY_FEED** <- fixed/length
-----------------
AID - INT, PRIMARY KEY, A_I <- *id of activity*
UID - INT <- *id of user* 
TYPE - ENUM(post,comment,like,etc) <- *type of activity*
RID - INT <- *id relative to activity type (for example "posts" table id)*
TIMESTAMP - DATETIME

**ACTIVITY_FEED_INDEX** <- fixed/length
------------------
UID - INT <- *id of the user that request the activity feed. (the follower)*
AID - INT <- *ID of the activity that the follower will seen*
TIMESTAMP - DATETIME <- *same timestamp of activity*
PRIMARY KEY uid,aid

**ACTIVITY_FEED_CACHE**
------------------
AID - INT <- *if of activity*
CACHE_DATA - TEXT <- *json string of activity parameters* //no search needed
```

the idea is to inserto into ACTIVITY_FEED_INDEX one row for everyone is following the user that made an activity. (Push mode)

Then, with a query like this:

```
SELECT cache.cache FROM activity_feed_index as index INNER JOIN activity_feed_cache AS cache ON cache.aid = index.aid WHERE index.uid = 'USER_ID'
```

the user will get all the activity of the users that he follow.

it is scalable? it is normalized? it is ok?

PS: at the moment i cannot use REDIS or other NoSQL system. So, only MYSQL.

PS: sorry for my bad english :O